# C - How to implement Set data structure?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, data-structures, set

Is there any tricky way to implement a set data structure (a collection of unique values) in C? All elements in a set will be of the same type and there is a huge RAM memory.

As I know, for integers it can be done really fast'N'easy using value-indexed arrays. But I'd like to have a very general Set data type. And it would be nice if a set could include itself.

Comment: I've the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537681/how-to-implement-a-set . Maybe it helps!

Comment: Shameless plug: I wrote an in-memory B-tree library in C: http://ccan.ozlabs.org/info/btree.html .  A B-tree serves essentially the same role as a binary tree regarding sets.

Comment: Of course, implementing sets which contain themselves is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There are **multiple ways of implementing** set (and map) functionality, for example:

- tree-based approach (ordered traversal)
- hash-based approach (unordered traversal)

Since **you mentioned value-indexed arrays**, let's try the hash-based approach which **builds naturally on top of the value-indexed array technique**.

*Beware of the [advantages and disadvantages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Features) of hash-based vs. tree-based approaches.*

You can design a **hash-set** (a special case of [hash-tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)) of pointers to *hashable* [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure)s, with [chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution), internally represented as a fixed-size array of buckets of *hashables*, where:

- all *hashables* in a bucket have the same hash value
- a bucket can be implemented as a [dynamic array *or* linked list of hashables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining)
- a *hashable*'s **hash value is used to index into the array of buckets** (hash-value-indexed array)
- one or more of the *hashables* contained in the hash-set could be (a pointer to) another hash-set, or even to the hash-set itself (i.e. **self-inclusion is possible**)

With large amounts of memory at your disposal, you can size your array of buckets generously and, in combination with a good hash method, drastically reduce the probability of [collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision), achieving virtually constant-time performance.

You would have to implement:

- the [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) for the type being hashed
- an equality function for the type being used to test whether two hashables are equal or not
- the hash-set `contains`/`insert`/`remove` functionality.

You can also use [open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing) as an alternative to maintaining and managing buckets.

Answer (score 6):

Sets are usually implemented as some variety of a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree).  [Red black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_black_tree) have good worst case performance.

These can also be used to build an [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) to allow key / value lookups.

This approach requires some sort of ordering on the elements of the set and the key values in a map.

I'm not sure how you would manage a set that could possibly contain itself using binary trees if you limit set membership to well defined types in C ... comparison between such constructs could be problematic.  You could do it easily enough in C++, though.

Answer (score 5):

The way to get genericity in C is by `void *`, so you're going to be using pointers anyway, and pointers to different objects are unique.  This means you need a hash map or binary tree containing pointers, and this will work for all data objects.

The downside of this is that you can't enter rvalues independently.  You can't have a set containing the value 5; you have to assign 5 to a variable, which means it won't match a random 5.  You could enter it as `(void *) 5`, and for practical purposes this is likely to work with small integers, but if your integers can get into large enough sizes to compete with pointers this has a very small probability of failing.

Nor does this work with string values.  Given `char a[] = "Hello, World!"; char b[] = "Hello, World!";`, a set of pointers would find `a` and `b` to be different.  You would probably want to hash the values, but if you're concerned about hash collisions you should save the string in the set and do a `strncmp()` to compare the stored string with the probing string.

(There's similar problems with floating-point numbers, but trying to represent floating-point numbers in sets is a bad idea in the first place.)

Therefore, you'd probably want a tagged value, one tag for any sort of object, one for integer value, and one for string value, and possibly more for different sorts of values.  It's complicated, but doable.

Answer (score 4):

If the maximum number of elements in the set (the cardinality of the underlying data type) is small enough, you might want to consider using a plain old array of bits (or whatever you call them in your favourite language).

Then you have a simple set membership check: bit n is 1 if element n is in the set.  You could even count 'ordinary' members from 1, and only make bit 0 equal to 1 if the set contains itself.

This approach will probably require some sort of other data structure (or function) to translate from the member data type to the position in the bit array (and back), but it makes basic set operations (union, intersection, membership test, difference, insertion, removal,compelment) very very easy.  And it is only suitable for relatively small sets, you wouldn't want to use it for sets of 32-bit integers I don't suppose.