# array that accepts a number only once(code doesn't work)

Tags: c, arrays

I need to make an array that accepts each number just once and if the user tries to insert a number more than once,then he must enter an other number...can anyone help me please?
I have tried this so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[5];
    int i,j,num;

    scanf("%d",&num);
    a[0]=num;

    for(i=1;i<5;++i){
        again: scanf("%d",&num);
        if(a[i]!=a[i-1])
            a[i]=num;
        else 
            goto again;
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%4d\n",a[i]);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

but the code just doesn't work and i don't know why

Comment: An array that accepts a value only once is often called a set.

Comment: Don't specify the language in the title. Place it in the tags.

Comment: What's the problem with this code? Be specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - How to implement Set data structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630738/c-how-to-implement-set-data-structure)

Comment: Note that using the word 'urgent' automagically generates downvotes but, as you are a 'member for today', I guess you don't care. The problem is, it also automagically gets your question ignored.

Comment: Just an observation: the else condition with `a[i]==a[i-1]`, which is negation of the if condition, is redundant.

Comment: You do realize you're only testing if the number entered is not equal to the previous number, but what if it is equal to one of the numbers before that? I.e. you may want to test against *all* previous values.

Comment: but how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is observed from your code that given array must be filled but it should not contain redundant values.

following code iterates until the array is filled with no redundant value, once the array is filled it terminates.

```
int a[5],i=1,k=0,p;
int num;
scanf("%d",&num);
a[0]=num;
while(i<5)
{
   scanf("%d",&num);
   for(p=0;p<=k;p++)
   {
       if(a[p]==num)
       {
          break;
        }

        if(p==(k))
        {

           a[i]=num;
           k=i;
           i++;
        }
   }


}


for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   printf("%d",a[i]);
}
```

hope this could help you

Answer (score 0):

You are just comparing the new entered value with the previous one in `a[i]!=a[i-1]`.

You better create a function to test the new value with the entire array, like

```
int valueExists(int num, int a[], int len) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (a[i] == num) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Make sure you adding the new value to the array only after testing the value is not there.

```
again: scanf("%d",&num);
if (valueExists(num, a, i)) {
    goto again;
} else {
    a[i] = num;
}
```

(The loop you created with the `goto` can be replaced by a `do`-`while` loop, but that is not the issue here)