# Creating a Set ADT in C

Tags: c, set, structure, adt

I am trying to create an ADT.

It is a dynamic set of finite elements. It must be implemented using arrays and linked lists.

Some operations include `add(set, x)` and `remove(set, x)`.

I understand that I first need to create an interface which will be common to both the array implementation and the linked list implementation.

I am however, not sure as regards the structure for this data type. What should I include?

```
struct test {
    int x;
    char y;
};
```

Something like that? Or let's say that I make the set exclusive for integers, what will the data structure involve?

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Need more info. Are you thinking of a finite set in the mathematical sense (where duplicate elements are allowed), or `set()` like in Python/Java/etc. (only has unique elements)? Are you trying to choose a data structure to optimize the `add()` and `remove()` operations, or perhaps others like `union()` or `intersect()`? Why arrays *and* linked lists? You have many data structures to choose from, why "must" it be implemented with those?

Comment: I'm thinking in a mathematical sense. Basically, all I have to do is add or remove an element, and then try out functions such as check_if_element_is_present(), union(), intersection(), cardinality()...

Comment: Basically, I need to create a dynamic set ADT and implement it using arrays and linked lists, but I'm confused and not sure from where to start, really.

Comment: My question is, do you have to use C or can you use C++? Do you have to use arrays/lists, or can you use trees/hashtables? Is this homework?

Comment: Yeah it's a project I'm working on at school. Have to use C and limited to arrays and linked lists.

Comment: See my answer for some good info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is for school, I'm not going to give you an implementation, but I'll point you in the right direction. Using arrays and lists screams 'hash table'. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2630785/3171324) for some good information.

For simplicity, let's assume it's a set of integers.
Essentially, you want an array `hash_table` of N 'buckets', i.e. lists. To add an element `x`, you do `hash_table[hash(x) % N]` to get the 'bucket' (list) `x` should go into, and add it to that list if it's not already in the list.

To remove `x`, do `hash_table[hash(x) % N]` to get your bucket, and remove `x` if it's there.

If you can implement those, `search(set, x)` is trivial. You can also try implementing `union(setA, setB)`, `intersect(setA, setB)`, `difference(setA, setB)`, `isSubset(setA, setB)`, etc. You may also want to peruse [the Wikipedia article on the Set ADT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28abstract_data_type%29), and do check out the entry in [The Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/set-data-structures.shtml) which includes links to implementations at the bottom.

Good luck, and happy coding. If you get stuck it's always OK to ask here on SO, just post code next time. :)

Comment: Aaa, thanks so much! Really helpful and informative. I'll get my head to it. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is the principle  of a structure, you can put all type of variable you want in it ..

I think you want to create an array of int.
Declaring like :

```
int tab["number of int you want"];
```

And access it like that :

```
tab["number of case of the int you want to access"];
```

Comment: If I were to make a set of numbers only though, I'd lose the purpose of the structure, no?

Comment: A structure is like a kind of variable. You can put "int", "char" etc ... in it, and look or modify value of this struct in your code.

Comment: Oh, yeah, makes sense. Basically, an array is a structure for example.

Comment: No, it's really different ! you can create an array of structure if you want. Structure is a kind of variable where you can put all of variable you want. Array is a way to save some variable.

Comment: I see. So in creating this Set ADT which stores numbers only as elements, I have to also create a data structure. The structure should just include an array of ints? Or should I also include any other variables, a pointer to the structure maybe...?

Thanks for the replies btw!

Comment: Array and Structure are 2 things different, i think you don't get the concept. If you want to create a data where you want some kind of variable like int, char, long, double, then you can create a structure. If you want to save, 100 int for example, create an array of int, you can put a number unlimited of int but can just put int in this array. Is it more clear ?

Comment: Yeah, kind of. I'm getting confused for the simple reason that I need to create a generic finite but dynamic set, initialized to hold any number of items of any kind without any particular order and no repeated values as an abstract data type, and since it's an ADT, I'm sure I need a structure somewhere, thing is, I don't know what the structure will cater for.