# How to implement Left Outer Join in C language

Tags: sql, c, data-structures

I was asked in an interview to implement SQL Left outer join in C language. Any thoughts,inputs how can I implement it.Thank you.

```
Input :

A
1,A,X
2,B,Y

B
2,M
3,N


Output of Left Outer Join between A and B is as below.

1,A,X, 
2,B,Y,M

#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char A[10][3] = { {1,A,X},{2,B,Y} };
    char B[10][2] = { {2,M} , {3,N} };

    for ( int i=0; i<2;i++ )
    {
         for(int j=0; j<2; j++ )
         {
               if( A[i][0] == B[j][0])
               printf("%c\t%c\t%c\t%c",A[i][0],A[i][1],A[i][2],B[i][1]);
               else
               printf("%c\t%c\t%c\t",A[i][0],A[i][1],A[i][2]);
         }           
   }
}
```

Regards,
SOAddict

Comment: pls share ur thoughts folks.. don't down vote it pls...

Comment: I think sooner or later code will be involved. At least that's how I'd do it. Consider what it would take, write an algorithm, write the matching code, and if the wheels fall off somewhere in there, bring specific questions back here.

Comment: Sounds to me like someone has a misunderstanding.  C does not have joins, inner outer or otherwise.  But within C you can call out to a database.  SO maybe they meant to ask 'how would you make a Left Outer Join to this RDBMS from C'

Comment: @Karl: SQL databases are written in some programming language, probably in many cases C or C++.  The question seems to be about how to implement that type of set operation in C.

Comment: there are algorithms to find common subsets (which is SQL inner join), you can start from there

Comment: I can write it in SQL.. and I know the answer...but I would like to do it in C.

Comment: I added some sample code here.. pls correct me or give me suggestions to improve it.. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a hash for key values in first table and save it's index and then you iterate over the second table key value and it there exists a key in hash then you will go to that index and merge.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of LEFT OUTER JOIN refers to a set operation where you output all elements of the "left" set, and additionally attempt to output matching elements from the "right" set by matching elements using a match criteria (often a primary and a foreign key).

You can create this type of [data structure in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630738/c-how-to-implement-set-data-structure).  For the sake of argument let's say that each set element is uniquely identified by an integer called Id.

Write code that outputs every element ("row") from your "left" set, and attempts to find a matching element from the right set using Id.  If it finds it, also output that element in that output row.  If not, output something indicating no match (SQL uses NULL).

A HashSet is an efficient data structure to use for the Ids, though there are other possibilities as well.