# How to separate a string into an array of the unique characters/ strings

Tags: c, algorithm

Basically I want to know if it is possible (if so how) to read a string from left to right and greedily terminate and append once that a new string is found. Eg.

"ABCABCABCABC" would give {"A" "B" "C" "AB" "CA" "BC" "ABC"}

I've been trying all day and all I end up with is broken code and crashing programs.

This is what I have that isn't working. The array is defined as  *a[linelen]

```
for(i =0; i < linelen ;i++)
{
    j=0;
    k=0; 
    tempstr[j] = input[i]; // move character from input to tempstring 
        for(k=0; k< array_size; k++) //search through array
        {
            tempstr[j] = input[i];
            if(*a != tempstr)//(strcmp(a,tempstr)) != 0) // if str not in array
            {
                printf("%s\n", a[0]); //debug
                a[array_size] = tempstr;
                //strcpy(a[array_size], tempstr); //copy str into array
                array_size++;
                memset(tempstr,0,linelen-i); // reset tempstr to empty
                j=0;

            } 
            if( *a == tempstr)//(strcmp(a[array_size],tempstr)) == 0)
            {
                j++;
                tempstr[j] = input[i+1];
                if(i != linelen -1) // otherwise if tempstr already in array
                {
                    printf("%s\n",a[0]); //debug
                    j++;
                    tempstr[j] = input[i+1];
                }
                else if (i == linelen -1) // if it is the last letter
                {
                    a[array_size] = tempstr;
                    //strcpy(a[array_size], tempstr); // add to array
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Can it be done? Sure, a lot of `strstr()` should eventually do it. Can it be done *efficiently*? No idea.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why you want BC and ABC and not BCA?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You should show us the code you consider best that handles this, and show what it produces before it crashes (you have got at least some diagnostic output, haven't you?), so we can see what you see.  We'll cheerfully help you resolve the problems in your code.  We won't simply write your program for you.

Comment: @maxime: when the code reads A, it is new; B is new; C is new.  Then it reads a new A but that's not new, so it reads the B too, for AB which is new; then CA is read; then BC is new, and finally AB is not new but ABC is.

Comment: Maybe trie? _https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie_

Comment: Oh, I see. OP only need to use a hashset and iterate then.

Comment: If your target (output) array is defined as `char *a[linelen];`, then the problem is simply that your accessing uninitialized memory — you've an array of pointers, but those pointers don't point anywhere, and you never allocate memory for them to point to.  Consider writing your own special-purpose variant of `strdup()`, with a signature such as `char *dup_char_range(const char *start, int len);` — this doesn't require a null-terminated string for input, which is probably appropriate for your problem.

Comment: Could you at least post the complete *function* you are using? Code without context is useless.

Comment: @EOF The only thing i didn't post were the assignments/definitions. What you see is all I have that isn't int i; etc.

Comment: @E.Munch: And no function prototype, arguments, return type...

Comment: Please review how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  That is what we should be given to work with.  Note that one reason for wanting to see your code is that it gives us a chance to see what level you're coding at, so we can avoid suggesting solutions that are way beyond your level of understanding.  You will need to use some string comparison function; simply comparing pointers is not going to work. OTOH, `strcmp()` requires null-terminated strings.  I think your code is not null-terminating the strings.

Comment: Given a string of length L, you'd need an array also of length L in the event that all characters are unique. This array would carry two pieces of information: a pointer to the first character of the unique substring and the length of the substring. Comparisons would be done using `memcmp` or `strncmp` due to the fact that you can't null-terminate each substring (else you separate "ababc" into "ab" and "bc" by overwriting the "a" in "abc"). If you wanted to use two separate arrays, one for sizes and one for pointers, you could do that as well. This solution assumes you don't know of `malloc`.

Comment: @E.Munch please don't remove parts that are needed to understand comments/answers already present, thanks. Btw, interesting problem, working on a solution just for fun, but I doubt it would be helpful without a lot of explanation.

Comment: I added benchmarks for everybody's program to the bottom of my answer in case you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that uses a simple character array to store the "seen" strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if 0
#define dbg(_fmt...)        printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbg(_fmt...)        /**/
#endif

// NOTE: could be char * and realloc if necessary
char seen[5000];

// find -- find old string
// RETURNS: 1=found, 0=no match
int
find(char *str)
{
    char *lhs;
    char *rhs;
    int foundflg;

    dbg("find: str='%s'\n",str);

    rhs = str;
    lhs = seen;
    dbg("find: lhs='%s'\n",seen);

    foundflg = 0;
    for (;  lhs < str;  ++lhs, ++rhs) {
        dbg("find: TRY lhs='%s' rhs='%s'\n",lhs,rhs);

        if (*lhs != *rhs) {
            dbg("find: SKIP\n");
            for (;  *lhs != 0;  ++lhs);
            rhs = str - 1;
            continue;
        }

        if ((*lhs == 0) && (*rhs == 0)) {
            dbg("find: MATCH\n");
            foundflg = 1;
            break;
        }

        if (*rhs == 0)
            break;
    }

    return foundflg;
}

void
sepstr(const char *inp)
{
    int chr;
    char *lhs;
    char *rhs;
    int finflg;

    lhs = seen;
    rhs = seen;
    finflg = 0;

    for (chr = *inp;  chr != 0;  chr = *++inp) {
        *rhs++ = chr;
        *rhs = 0;

        if (find(lhs)) {
            finflg = 1;
            continue;
        }

        printf("%s\n",lhs);
        lhs = ++rhs;
        finflg = 0;
    }

    if (finflg)
        printf("%s\n",lhs);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

#if 1
    sepstr("ABCABCABCABC");
#else
    sepstr("ABCABCABCABCABC");
#endif
}
```

Here's a second way to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char out[500];

#ifdef BIG
#define SEEN 256
#else
#define SEEN (26 + 1)
#endif

char seen[SEEN][SEEN];

void
sepstr(const char *inp)
{
    int chr;
    char *prv;
    char *rhs;

    prv = seen[0];

    rhs = out;
    for (chr = *inp;  chr != 0;  chr = *++inp) {
        *rhs++ = chr;

#ifndef BIG
        chr = (chr - 'A') + 1;
#endif

        if (prv[chr]) {
            prv = seen[chr];
            continue;
        }

        *rhs = 0;
        printf("%s\n",out);

        prv[chr] = 1;
        rhs = out;
        prv = seen[0];
    }

    if (rhs > out) {
        *rhs = 0;
        printf("%s\n",out);
    }
}

int
main(void)
{

#if 1
    sepstr("ABCABCABCABC");
#else
    sepstr("ABCABCABCABCABC");
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Here are some benchmarks for everybody's program (time in ns and printf nop'ed):

```
       first      minimum author
         527          137 craig1 -- original -- uses single seen char array
         146           39 craig2 -- modified -- uses 2D seen table
       45234        45234 felix1 -- original -- may only be executed once
       40460          656 felix2 -- uses fixed input
          24           18 machine1 -- original -- uses buffer[20][20] on stack
         908          417 machine2 -- modified -- uses global buffer[20][20]
       43089         1120 milevyo1 -- original
       42719          711 milevyo2 -- parseString tmp is stack buffer no malloc
        7957          429 milevyo3 -- NewNode uses fixed pool no malloc
        7457          380 milevyo4 -- removed linked list
```

Comment: Yes that's interesting, although not quite comparable that way because not all solutions have the same flexibility. Your approach to store it all contiguously is probably great for cache locality. A lot of time is typically spent in heap allocations. I wonder whether my idea to have "buckets" per string length could help with scaling.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Added new way that is 4x faster.  You're right.  Cache "hot" is important.  In the table, left column is first time (cache cold) and second is best of N runs (cache hot).  Your orig lost on stdin.  I tweaked it ala others (e.g. doit("ABCABCABCABC"))--major speedup.  Note, for mine, cache cold and -DBIG is slow, but cache hot it's the same. Your "buckets" seem to be like a hash.  If so, would strlen + first char be a better key?  (e.g. a 2D lookup table)  Or, am I missing it?

Comment: Using the loop to drive the tests (e.g. `for/continue`, or `for( ... i+=step)`, or even `goto`) are by far the most efficient way to approach a number of iterative situations.  Good thinking.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks.  I failed on google's foobar challenge, "minions bored game".  Correct way was form of dynamic programming, so did some research, and started looking for use cases:  See my answer in "vampire challenge" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834843/need-help-for-off-by-one-error-in-c-program-for-finding-factors/32860875#32860875 .  For the current problem, I just thought up the 2nd algorithm organically, but, I think it's "dynamic programming with tabulation" [technique to avoid expensive list/tree searches] and get O(n) vs O(n^2) or worse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You just have to keep track of the different string occurrences. The easiest way is to use a Set.

Edit: see here for how to implement a Set in C: [How to implement a Set data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630738/c-how-to-implement-set-data-structure)

Edit2: you can find an implementation here (I did not test it): [HashSet.c](https://github.com/avsej/hashset.c)

Comment: It is, I suppose, a direct and correct answer to the question, but it is not dreadfully helpful.  Which standard C header provides a `Set` type?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's quite easy to reimplement a simple hashset. You only need an array of linked lists and a hash function.

Comment: @Maxime: We need to see the OP's code before we can assess whether an array of linked lists with dynamic memory allocation (and even structures) is within his range of knowledge.  My gut feel is that such suggestions would confuse him more than help him — his knowledge is not yet at that level.  I hope I'm wrong, but without seeing their code, no-one can be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I have no idea what a set is or how to implement one. I've done some quick googling and I can't seem to understand how it can be implemented somewhat easily

Comment: @E.Munch, I have edited the answer to add further info.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've edited with the code that I have.

Comment: With the code posted, the first two sentences of this answer remain accurate.  The x-ref to the SO question is interesting (thanks for that), but using sets is overkill for the context.

Answer (score 0):

Here,this should do :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "ABCABCABCABC";

    //length of str
    size_t len = strlen(str);

    //buffer to hold extracted strings
    char buffer[20][20];

    //i : 1st buffer index , j : 2nd buffer index , n : variable used in the loop
    size_t i = 1 , j = 0 , n = 0 ;

    //store str[0] and '\0' to form a string : buffer[0]
    buffer[0][0] = str[0];
    buffer[0][1] = '\0';

    //has the string been found ?
    bool found = false;

    //n should start by 1 since we stored str[0] int buffer already
    for( n = 1 ; n < len ; n++ )
    {
        //store str[n] in buffer , increment j , and store '\0' to make a string
        buffer[i][j] = str[n];
        j++;
        buffer[i][j] = '\0';

        //this loop check if the string stored is found in the entire buffer.
        for( int x = 0 ; x < i ; x++ )
        {
            if( strcmp(buffer[i],buffer[x]) == 0 )
            {
                found = true;
            }
        }

        //if the string has not been found,increment i,to make a new string in the next iteration
        if( found == false)
        {
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }
        //reset the bool value
        found = false;
    }

    //print the strings stored in buffer.
    for( int x = 0 ; x < i ; x++ )
    {
        printf("%s\n",buffer[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added benchmarks for everybody's program to the bottom of my answer in case you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fully dynamic solution in C99, but it's still draft code (not checking for out of memory conditions at all) and maybe quite inefficient (doesn't use hashing for example):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* a string builder */
typedef struct sb
{
    size_t capacity;
    size_t len;
    char str[];
} sb;

/* a container of substrings, represented by string builders */
typedef struct strcontainer
{
    size_t capacity;
    size_t len;
    sb **substrings;
} strcontainer;

/* global maximum length of substrings seen so far */
static size_t maxlen;

/* container instances */
static strcontainer *containers;

/* initialize a new container */
static void strcontainer_init(strcontainer *self)
{
    self->capacity = 16;
    self->len = 0;
    self->substrings = malloc(16 * sizeof(sb *));
}

/* create a new string builder */
static sb *sb_create(void)
{
    sb *self = malloc(sizeof(sb) + 16);
    self->capacity = 16;
    self->len = 0;
    self->str[0] = 0;
    return self;
}

/* append a character to a string builder */
static sb *sb_append(sb *self, int c)
{
    self->str[self->len++] = (char) c;
    if (self->len == self->capacity)
    {
        self->capacity *= 2;
        self = realloc(self, sizeof(sb) + self->capacity);
    }
    self->str[self->len] = 0;
    return self;
}

/* get plain C string from a string builder */
static const char *sb_str(const sb *self)
{
    return &(self->str[0]);
}

/* check whether a substring with the contents of the given string builder is
 * already present and increase maximum length and count of containers if
 * necessary */
static int sb_ispresent(const sb *self)
{
    if (self->len > maxlen)
    {
        size_t oldlen = maxlen + 1;
        maxlen = self->len;
        containers = realloc(containers,
                (maxlen + 1) * sizeof(strcontainer));
        for (; oldlen <= maxlen; ++oldlen)
        {
            strcontainer_init(containers + oldlen);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    strcontainer *container = containers + self->len;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < container->len; ++i)
    {
        if (!strcmp(sb_str(self), sb_str(container->substrings[i])))
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/* check whether container has space left and if not, expand it */
static void strcontainer_checkexpand(strcontainer *self)
{
    if (self->len == self->capacity)
    {
        self->capacity *= 2;
        self->substrings = realloc(self->substrings,
                self->capacity * sizeof(sb *));
    }
}

/* insert a string builder as new substring in a container */
static void strcontainer_insert(strcontainer *self, sb *str)
{
    strcontainer_checkexpand(self);
    self->substrings[self->len++] = str;
}

/* insert this string builder instance in the appropriate containers */
static void sb_insert(sb *self)
{
    strcontainer_insert(containers, self);
    strcontainer_insert(containers + self->len, self);
}

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    size_t i = 0;

    /* idea here: allocate a global container and one for each substring
     * length. start with a maximum length of 1, makes 2 containers */
    containers = malloc(2 * sizeof(strcontainer));
    strcontainer_init(containers);
    strcontainer_init(containers+1);
    maxlen = 1;

    /* string builder for the substring */
    sb *builder = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        /* on newline, output what we have so far */
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            while (i < containers->len)
            {
                puts(sb_str(containers->substrings[i++]));
            }
            continue;
        }

        /* ignore carriage returns, maybe ignore some other characters
         * here too? */
        if (c == '\r') continue;

        /* append each character to the string builder */
        if (!builder) builder = sb_create();
        builder = sb_append(builder, c);

        /* check whether we have seen the string already after every append */
        if (!sb_ispresent(builder))
        {
            /*then insert and restart with a new string builder */
            sb_insert(builder);
            builder = 0;
        }
    }

    /* more output after EOF */
    while (i < containers->len)
    {
        puts(sb_str(containers->substrings[i++]));
    }

    /* if we still have a builder, there was some non-unique text left over
     * at the end of the input */
    if (builder)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Left over: `%s'\n", sb_str(builder));
    }

    /* might want to clean up on the heap with some free()s ...
     * not strictly necessary at end of program */

    return 0;
}
```

example:

```
> echo "ABCABCABCABCABC" | ./greadystring
A
B
C
AB
CA
BC
ABC
Left over: `ABC'
```

Comment: I added benchmarks for everybody's program to the bottom of my answer in case you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

i am using linked list to avoid duplicate items. check the output at the end.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct NODE NODE;
struct NODE{
    char value[20];
    NODE *next;
};
NODE *head=NULL;
/*_________________________________________________
*/
NODE *FindNode(char *p){
    NODE *tmp=head;
    while(tmp){
        if(_stricmp(tmp->value,p)==0) break;
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
    return tmp;
}
/*_________________________________________________
*/
NODE *NewNode(char *p){
    NODE *tmp=calloc(1,sizeof(NODE));
    if(tmp){
        strcpy(tmp->value,p);
    }
    return tmp;
}
/*_________________________________________________
*/

int AddNode(char *p){

    NODE * tmp=FindNode(p);
    if(!tmp){
        if((tmp=NewNode(p))){
            if(!head)
                head=tmp;
            else{
                NODE *_tmp=head;
                while(_tmp->next)_tmp=_tmp->next;
                _tmp->next=tmp;
            }
            return 1;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
/*_________________________________________________
*/
void printNodes(void){
    NODE *tmp=head;
    printf("{");
    while(tmp){
        printf("\"%s\"",tmp->value);
       tmp=tmp->next;
        if(tmp)printf(",");
    }
    printf("}\n");
 }
/*_________________________________________________
*/
void deleteNodes(void){
    NODE *tmp=head;
    while(tmp){
       head=tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
        tmp=head;
    }
 }
/*_________________________________________________
*/
void parseString(char *buff){
    int  buffSize=  strlen(buff);
    if(!buffSize) return;

    char *tmp;
    char *ptr=buff;

    int j=1,n=0;

    for(ptr=buff;n<buffSize;ptr+=j){
        tmp=calloc(sizeof(char),j+1);
        strncpy(tmp,ptr,j);
        if(!*tmp){
            free(tmp);
            break;
        }

        if(!AddNode(tmp)){
            j++;
            ptr-=j;

        }else
            n+=j;
        free(tmp);
    }

    printf("%s\n",buff);
    printNodes();
    printf("\n");
    deleteNodes();

}
int main(void){
    parseString("ABCABCABCABC");
    parseString("ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC");
    return 0;
}
```

here is the output:

```
ABCABCABCABC
{"A","B","C","AB","CA","BC","ABC"}

ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC
{"A","B","C","AB","CA","BC","ABC","ABCA","BCAB","CABC"}
```

Comment: A linked list is probably one of the *least* efficient approaches, still as long as it's producing correct output it's an answer :). Nevertheless some comments on the code: 1. What's `_stricmp()`? Non-standard and as the rest of the code looks standard conforming, why introduce this? 2. Avoid identifiers starting with an underscore in C, they're reserved (google for details) 3. Please don't adopt this ugly old Microsoft winapi style of using all uppercase type names. 4. instead of visual separators, *real* comments explaining the function's purpose would be more helpful.

Comment: i was doing some tests , you just can replace it with strcmp()

Comment: except that will be case sensitive, but I guess that's ok (not specified in the question and a sane assumption), I just did it that way. Take my points *3* and *4* as some opinion on style in general (whatever you make from it), but the remark about leading underscores *might* be imortant :)

Comment: I'm talking about your use of a variable named `_tmp`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen tahnk you for your advises, i really appreciate that.

Comment: I added benchmarks for everybody's program to the bottom of my answer in case you're interested.