# TreeSet Vs Tree

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I have few questions related to Collection Frameworks's `TreeSet` that I am putting here.

1. Is the only functional difference between `TreeSet` and `ArrayList` classes is constraint of unique elements and elements being sorted too in `TreeSet`?
2. Presence of prefix `Tree` creates a confusion about visualizing a `TreeSet` as a hierarchical data structure or linear one. Mathematical sets are linear data structures while name `Tree` in computing indicates a hierarchical one.

   Is there really any similarity / relation between `Tree` Data Structure and Java's `TreeSet` or name `TreeSet` just a coincidence?

I mean, it doesn't seem that set will have anything to do with parent - child relationships.

**EDIT** - Looks like, I was confused about what I am trying to ask which got clarified after pondering over comments and answers. I guess, my main question should have been "why mathematical set DS ( sorted or unsorted ) is implemented via a Tree?" and that is a duplicate of [How to implement Set data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630738/c-how-to-implement-set-data-structure)

Comment: Look at the [source code for `TreeMap.getEntry`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#336), which `TreeSet.get` uses. There is a clear left/right descent into a tree structure there.

Comment: Reading a [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is sometimes a good practice.

Comment: Thanks Andy and Agad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the only functional difference between TreeSet and ArrayList
>   classes is constraint of unique elements and elements being sorted too
>   in TreeSet?

That is major difference, apart from internal implementation, and this enables TreeSet to provide functions like subset, tailset, headSet which are not possible with a ArrayList.

> Presence of prefix Tree creates a confusion about visualizing a
>   TreeSet as a hierarchical data structure or linear one. Mathematical
>   sets are linear data structures while name Tree in computing indicates
>   a hierarchical one.

Yes, it is hierarchical structure. Internally the implementation is a Red-black binary tree.

> Is there really any similarity / relation between Tree Data Structure
>   and Java's TreeSet or name TreeSet just a coincidence?

The internal implementation is a R-B binary tree.

On a side note, since these two are different data structures, time complexity of TreeSet is completely from ArrayList for same set of operations. For ex: add ArrayList is O(1) but for TreeSet it is O(logn), search for arrayList is O(n) and for TreeSet is is O(logn) and so on...

Answer (score 1):

TreeSet is real tree, not coincidence.
So there's many difference with Arraylist.
 For example performance ( I mean Big-O ) is totally different.

Answer (score 1):

Internally TreeSet is present as a Tree structure. So this fact influences on operations complexity. Most of operation require O(log n) actions for TRee based structures but array based structures work in constant time for most used read only operation. So HashSet is based on array and allows const time access to its values.

Also they provide different functionality. HashSet just stores elements. It behaves like math set as you sad, in linear manner.
But TreeSet provides more operation: take a look at NavigableSet and SortedSer interfaces it implements. Elements of TreeSet are always sorted. But in the same time they require setting sorting rules for them provided by impelemting Comparable interface or using side Comparator object.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of usage it is just a `Set`, plus some extra goodies like having a definite sequence. However, it is internally implemented as a tree.

The naming convention here is similar as with `HashSet`, another `Set` internally implemented as a hash table.