# free memories in c and got unknown error that free(&p->data) not working

Tags: c, free

I have a structure of nodes down here:

```
struct N *mknode(struct N *xp, struct N *yp, struct N *zp, long n)
{
    struct N *p = malloc(sizeof(struct N));
    p->x = xp;
    p->y = yp;
    p->z = zp;
    p->data = n;
    return p;
}
```

my task is to free each node exactly once, so that there are neither double frees nor memory leaks

and my codes can only include stdlib.h and "freegraph.h", i put stdio.h because i need to use the printf function to show which line of codes not working

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "freegraph.h"

#include <stdio.h>

// construct a linked list
typedef struct node {
    struct N * val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;

typedef enum { false, true } bool;

node_t head = { NULL, NULL };


// check if any duplicated in the linked list
bool check_duplicate (node_t * head, struct N * val) {
    bool duplicate = false;
    node_t * current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        if ( current->val == val) {
            duplicate = true;
            return duplicate;
        }
        else {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    return duplicate;
}

// adding an item to the end of the linked list
void push (node_t * head, struct N * val) {
    node_t * current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    current->next->val = val;
    current->next->next = NULL;
}
//deallocate recursive function, printf to see which line is working
void deallocate(struct N *p)
{
    if (p != NULL) {
        if (!check_duplicate(&head, p)) {
            deallocate (p->x);
            printf("1\n");
            deallocate (p->y);
            printf("2\n");
            deallocate (p->z);
            printf("3\n");
            free(&p->data);
            printf("4\n");
            push (&head, p);
            printf("5\n");
        }
    }
```

}

however my programs only print out 1,2,3 and then it will stop and exit itself.
so i am assuming free(&p->data) isn't working, but i dont really know what im doing wrong.

Here is my test codes:

```
    p1 = mknode(NULL, NULL, NULL, 1);
    p2 = mknode(NULL, NULL, NULL, 10);
    p3 = mknode(NULL, NULL, NULL, 100);
    p4 = mknode(p1, p2, p3, 3000);
    p1 = mknode(NULL, NULL, NULL, 1);
    p2 = mknode(NULL, NULL, NULL, 10);
    p3 = mknode(NULL, NULL, NULL, 100);
    p5 = mknode(p1, p2, p3, 4000);
    p5 = mknode(p4, p5, NULL, 50000);
    p6 = mknode(p5, NULL, NULL, 100000);

    // now make it harder by sharing and cycles
    p1->x = p5;
    p2->y = p4;
    p2->z = p2;
    p6->y = p5;
    p6->z = p6; 

    deallocate(p6);
```

Comment: @L_Church what u talking about?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through in a debugger to see what is happening?

Comment: s/free(&p->data);/free(p->data);/

Comment: any debugger suggest? @ChristianGibbons

Comment: @BjornA. what does it mean?

Comment: @HinokWong GDB is the go-to debugger.  A typical IDE will have a debugger built in.  It really is essential to programming to learn how to use one.  As for what Bjorn said, his comment was in the form of a regular expression.  He was telling you to replace `free(&p->data);` with `free(p->data);`

Comment: If the nodes can link to each other in a loop (as your use of the `duplicate` function suggests), then the solution is to use a graph traversal algorithm such as DFS (which would require additional storage). If you had allocated all nodes in blocks of memory then this would be far simpler.

Comment: @HinokWong Remove the ampersand so free() gets the right argument. It wants the address stored in the 'data' struct member , not the address of the member.

Comment: @BjornA. Inside free() must be "void * " and if p->data it is type long integer, so free(p->data) wont work

Comment: My bad. Why free p->data at all?

Comment: You should only free things that have an associated `malloc` family call to allocate them.

Comment: **Since you tagged as C++**, I'll assume you're working in C++. 1) The `typedef` is not required in C++.  2) The `struct` keyword is not required when creating instances of structures.  3) Prefer to use smart pointers 4) Initialize the link fields in the constructor of your `struct`. 5) Use `new` to dynamically allocate memory (the `malloc` function doesn't call the constructor).  6) Use `delete` to free up the allocated memory.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Since he specifically mentioned C in the title, I think it's a safe assumption that it was a typical case of over-tagging.  I removed the C++ tag in an edit, but it hasn't been approved yet :/

Comment: Remove `free(&p->data);`.

Comment: Tip: delete `p1->x = p5;
    p2->y = p4;
    p2->z = p2;
    p6->y = p5;
    p6->z = p6;` and get code to work.  Then add back with the additional code to handle cycles.  Suggest adding a `usage_count` member to `struct N`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: I would prefer you not to remove the tag.  Let the OP.  This will help the OP realize that C and C++ are two different languages.  I'm not sure which edition of C contains the `bool` type; in the C++ language, the `bool` type is standard.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews my bad, i removed C++ after realizing they are different, thanks

Comment: @ChristianGibbons thanks i approved it

Comment: @ThomasMatthews C added `bool` in C99, as a typedef for the newly added `_Bool` type.  However it looks like he did his own typdef here, anyways.

Comment: @HinokWong does the question state that the implementation of `mknode` is modifiable or fixed?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog fixed

Comment: @chux thanks for ur tip, it helped me a lot

Comment: @HinokWong You can even post an answer below to your own question if you later figure out a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given that no other modifications can be made to the provided functions and data type, the (abstract) data structure required to solve this problem efficiently is a **set**. These always contain only one copy of every unique element.

Procedure:

- Create an empty set
- Perform a recursive Depth-First Search on the given starting node
- For each node visited, stop recursing if the set contains it, otherwise add it to the set and continue
- After recursion finishes completely, call `free` on every node in the set (without doing anything to their child pointers)

C-style pseudocode:

```
static void dealloc_recursive(struct N *p, Set* s)
{
   if (p == NULL) return;

   if (set_contains(s, p)) return;

   dealloc_recursive(p->x, s);
   dealloc_recursive(p->y, s);
   dealloc_recursive(p->z, s);
}

void deallocate(struct N *p)
{
   Set* set = set_create_empty();

   dealloc_recursive(p, set);

   for (struct N *p in set)
      free(p);

   set_destroy(set);
}
```

Two common types of sets spring to mind (present in Java's library; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630738/c-how-to-implement-set-data-structure) for more on solutions for C):

- Hash sets: a hash table. Containment queries are (amortized) constant time. Might use more memory to account for collisions and chaining.
- Tree sets: a (balanced) binary search tree (typically). Containment queries are logarithmic time. Uses a fixed percentage more memory for node metadata.

A quick Google search yields [this](https://github.com/avsej/hashset.c) example implementation. If you have a very large number of nodes, consider using *Judy arrays*. There are countless many others, possibly more efficient.