# Minimizing time complexity when looping over two arrays

Tags: c, for-loop, time-complexity

For a intro computer science class we have to write a function that finds the intersection of two arrays, which each unique element only being shown once and without allocating more space than we need.

For example:

> array A = {1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5}
>
> array B = {2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6}
>
> intersection of A and B = {2, 3, 5}

How can I accomplish this without looping over the both arrays twice? As it stands I have:

```
//find how large of an array I'll need
for array A 
  for array A
    if A[i] is already somewhere earlier in array A
      stop
    else 
      loop through array B 
      if A[i] is in array B, increment a counter


declare a new array of size counter  

//add unique elements to the array
for array A 
  for array A
    if A[i] is already somewhere earlier in array A
      stop
    else 
      loop through array B 
      if A[i] is in array B, add it to the new array
```

It seems like this would be really inefficient I have two nearly identical nested for loops. If I was using python I could just append unique elements to list, but is there a way I could do something similar in C? I could just declare an array of the maximum size I could need, but I'm trying to minimize the space complexity.

Comment: Are the arrays guaranteed to be sorted, as they are in your example?  If so, then you can do a two-finger walk.

Comment: No, I didn't think about that when making the example.

Comment: Well, one approach would be to sort both arrays in place, then do the two-finger walk.  That would be O(n*log(n)), as opposed to O(n**2).

Answer (score 0):

If your are aware of sets you can use that. The time-complexity will be `O(n)`

You can know more about set and how to implement one in `C` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630738/c-how-to-implement-set-data-structure).

Then you can do something like this (written in Java):

```
public int[] intersection(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
    Set<Integer> set1 = getSet(nums1);
    Set<Integer> set2 = getSet(nums2);

    Set<Integer> ans = new HashSet<>();

    for(Integer i: set1) {
        if(set2.contains(i)) {
            ans.add(i);
        }
    }

    int[] ret = new int[ans.size()];

    int count = 0;
    for(Integer i: ans) {
        ret[count] = i;
        count++;
    }

    return ret;
}

public Set<Integer> getSet(int[] arr) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

    for(int a: arr) { set.add(a); }
    return set;
}
```

Comment: A Java answer for a C question?  Where C has no native sets?

Comment: @GregA.Woods Added a link for that.