# Print values that occur at least once in an array in C

Tags: arrays, c

In the program, I form an array that looks something like this:

```
unsigned short types[] = {1,1,2,3,4,100,7,8,1,1};
```

I need to find and output the number of unique values that occur in an array. For this example, the unique values are: 1,2,3,4,100,7,8 and there are only 7 of them.
That is, the program should display:

```
total number of unique values in the given array - 7.
```

The range of possible values in the array is 0-0xFF (0 - 255).
The size of the array `types` is 65535.
The array can be modified and anything can be done with it to get an answer, but it is desirable that the complexity of the calculations is not great.
How can this be done in C?

Comment: You can use 256 buckets initialized to 0. Traverse the array and use the buckets to count occurances of each value. Then count the number of buckets with value > 0.

Comment: Hint: you need an array of `int`s that contains 256 entries, each entry containing the number of occurences.

Comment: A [set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630738/c-how-to-implement-set-data-structure) is what you want, in the general case, but perhaps overkill if the range of values is limited to 0-255.

Comment: @jarmod no sets needed here (it would be overkill), the range of values is restricted from 0 to 255, therefore a simple array is good enough.

Comment: @Jabberwocky u mean I should i should form matrix unique like so:
possible value                 | 0 | 1 | 2 | ... | 255 |
number of occurrences  | 0 | 0 | 10 | ... | 2 |
like so and then just look for non zero value, count them then print?

Comment: @Fuonder exactly. Like `int counts[256]; ...`. `counts[0]` would contains the number of occurences of 0, `counts[1]` would contains the number of occurences of 1, etc. TGhe complexity will be O(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [@wohlstad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72029407/print-values-that-occur-at-least-once-in-an-array-in-c#comment127273347_72029407) 's comment on the question, this following function would take the array and its size as parameters, and print the answer:
Edit: added a main to show example of use and changed the return so it can more easily handle errors, in case something was unclear for the user asking the question.
Edit2: As [@jarmod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72029407/print-values-that-occur-at-least-once-in-an-array-in-c/72029598#comment127285729_72029598) pointed out, this solution outputs the total number that occurred once, which is not what you asked.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int print_unique_values_in_array(unsigned short* array, int len) {
   
   if (len <= 0 || array == NULL) {
       // error message
       return -1;
   }

   int occurrences[256] = {0}; // initialize all values to 0.

   for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
       if (array[i] > 255 || array[i] < 0) {
           // error message
           return -1;
       }
       occurrences[array[i]] += 1;
   }
   
   int unique_occurrences = 0;

   for (int i=0; i < 256; i++) {
       if (occurrences[i] == 1)
           unique_occurrences += 1;
   }
   printf("total number of unique values in the given array - %d\n", unique_occurrences);
   return unique_occurrences;
}


int main() {

    unsigned short types[10] = {1,1,2,3,4,100,7,8,1,1};
    int size = 10;

    int unique_occurrences = print_unique_values_in_array(types, size);
    if (unique_occurrences < 0) {
        // ...
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As per your definition of unique values, the function should be the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int print_unique_values_in_array(unsigned short* array, int len) {
   
   if (len <= 0 || array == NULL) {
       // error message
       return -1;
   }

   int occurrences[256] = {0}; // initialize all values to 0.

   for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
       if (array[i] > 255 || array[i] < 0) {
           // error message
           return -1;
       }
       occurrences[array[i]] += 1;
   }
   
   int unique_occurrences = 0;

   for (int i=0; i < 256; i++) {
       if (occurrences[i] > 0)
           unique_occurrences += 1;
   }
   printf("total number of unique values in the given array - %d\n", unique_occurrences);
   return unique_occurrences;
}


int main() {

    unsigned short types[10] = {1,1,2,3,4,100,7,8,1,1};
    int size = 10;

    int unique_occurrences = print_unique_values_in_array(types, size);
    if (unique_occurrences < 0) {
        // ...
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still learning about these markdown/stackoverflow features. I edited my answer to include some error checking. Thanks for the tip !

Comment: It seems to me that either I did not quite understand you, or the code does not work correctly with the input data. The initial array, which is taken as input, contains 65535 elements in the range [0-255], and it turns out that in the first loop I go beyond it, which leads to a Segmentation Error.

Comment: did you pass the function len = 65535 ?

Comment: yes, input array len is 65535

Comment: Does it work for the example you posted in your question ?

Comment: "Size of array - types is 65535". I'll explain again. i have unsigned short array with 65535 elements. Each element it is a number in range 0-255. I have to find how many different numbers is in initial array.

Comment: pass the array and 65535 as the second argument to the function, It should work (if you subsitute the '//desired error management' block  for something (return ; for example). You could also add some error message to debug and see what is happening. The problem should be on your input, not the function itself

Comment: Okay, I have another problem. In this code
```
for (int i=0; i < 256; i++) {
       if (occurrences[i] == 1)
           unique_occurrences += 1;
   }
```
you meant that there would be 1 number at a time, right? Because in my array Occurrences, all the values ​​are about 200 approximately. So i need to look for non-zero value, and everything should work?

Comment: I added an example of use with a main that you can run on your computer and see what differences your program has with it.

Comment: occurrences will have a value of 1 for each entry that has only occurred once. If it occurred 0 times it is not a unique ocurrence, and if it occurred more than 1 it is also not a unique occurence.

Comment: It's too much with Main XD, but thanks. Everything works, but I can’t understand why, if I give the size of the variable to the input of the function, and not a specific number ( func(types, sizeof(types)) ), for some reason in the first loop there are calls to the limits. For example, with test data:
100 - elements
The program accesses 101 element of array and crashes with an error.

Comment: upd: it is my fault, your func is great and everything ok. Thank you so much! < 3

Comment: care. sizeof(types) will always be 8 since it is taking the size of the pointer (unsigned short*), not the array itself. You should pass the number as in the main I provided, otherwise theres no other way to tell the size of the array from the function. C works that way :P,

Comment: @carce-bo Given `unsigned short types[] = {1,1,2,3,4,100,7,8,1,1};`, `sizeof(types)` is 20, not 8.  The usually way is `element_count = sizeof types / sizeof types[0];` and then `print_unique_values_in_array(types, element_count);`

Comment: I did not know that. I will use that from now on whenever I use fixed size arrays instead  of pointers. Thank you once again

Comment: As written, the answer does not provide the correct result. The answer has a different definition of 'unique' to the question and yields a different result. The question doesn't care if 1 appears multiple times but this answer does. The question expects the result 7 for the given testcase but this answer results in 6 (because it treats the multiple instances of 1 as 'not unique').

Comment: @jarmod I edited the answer to include the actual answer to his question. I find it a very unnecessary use of the word 'unique' but it is true he asked for what you said.